# What does "Permanent "Allow" commands in private windows" in Noscript 2.6.9.10 employed in Tor browser mean?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, noscript

Tor browser version 4.0.3 employes Noscript version 2.6.9.10 and one has observed a new drop in command in this Noscript version. Namely: "Permanent "Allow" commands in private windows".
What is the purpose of this drop in command in Noscript and why it is showing up?

Answer (score 1):

This was [removed](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-browser-404-released) with Tor Browser 4.0.4. It was there accidentally.